# append to column and not rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of text files with 1 column of data in them.  They are all the same length (231 rows x 1 column) and I just want to combine them into 1 csv file for editing.  How do I do this?  I've tried append, concat.  I keep getting output that inserts the column as a row.  What am I don't wrong?

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd

files = sorted(glob.glob('C:\\Users\\jes6785\\Downloads\\test\\*.txt'))

dfs = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(230)) 
dfs = dfs.drop([0],axis=1) 
print(dfs)

for file in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    print(data)
```

none of the next lines work

```
    dfs = pd.concat([dfs, data], axis=1)
    dfs = dfs.append(data)
    df = df.join((data), Index([0]))
```

I want 231 rows by 2 columns

I keep getting 2696 rows x 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

as i see, your problem is that you create empty **dfs**. Here is code example without it and concat is still ok.

```
import pandas as pd

# simulate dataframes reading
alph = 'absdefghi'
frames = []
for _ in range(5):
    # here instead of making new dataframe do read_csv
    df = pd.DataFrame([''.join(np.random.choice(list(alph), 10)) for _ in range(10)])
    frames.append(df)

# concat all frames, no need to initialize empty df earlier
final_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all the files together you should add them in a list and then use pd.concat.

I would change your script like this:

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd

files = sorted(glob.glob('C:\\Users\\jes6785\\Downloads\\test\\*.txt'))


list_to_concat = []

for file in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
    list_to_concat.append(data)

dfs = pd.concat(list_to_concat, axis=1, ignore_index=True) #ignore index is not necesary
```